# What is externalip?

Tags: network

My Glassswire app shows that avast has connected to a suspicious host "myexternalip" [image: Is it safe and what does it mean if the host ip is 0.0.0.0 as in the pic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try going to https://myexternalip.com/ in a browser? It appears to be an innocuous website that shows your external IP address.

However, the reason it is being flagged could be due to the fact that some malware uses it to determine your external IP address, see [this Symantec writeup](https://www.symantec.com/security_response/earthlink_writeup.jsp?docid=2016-101811-2408-99).

Also, if I am reading the image correctly, it appears that Avast made the request. This seems reasonable, assuming it really is a legitimate Avast service. If that is the case, there is likely no reason to worry.

As @ewanm89 pointed out, Avast may be proxying web traffic, and the request could have been made by another application. It is still hard to know for sure without more information.

Comment: Only thing I would say, is that avast proxies web requests to scan them for malware, so something else could have sent it and it is being flagged by glasswire as coming from avast proxy anyway.